# 'User joined chat' fly-in is colored white

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, chat

When a user joins a chat room, their avatar and username fly down from the top of the screen to join the rest of the users in the sidebar.  In our shiny new dark-styled chatroom, this fly-in box is still styled in the old white background style.

Picture courtesy [PeterDC](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2841/peterd):

[image: Image of white on dark]

Comment: I uploaded a screenshot here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/43YTV.png However, I lack edit privileges, so it's up to you to add it in.

Comment: Whoo hoo! A linky to my profile! :P

Comment: @PeterDC Thanks, I just got my first Mac, and I'm not used to all the nitty gritty yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great point. I never considered changing that part, but you're right, it's better. Done!